# Checking if a number is prime

Tags: c++, performance, beginner, c++11, primes

Is there a better way to check if a number is a prime?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

bool doAgain();
bool isPrime(int num);

int main()
{
    do {
        int num = 0;
        do {
            cout << "Enter a positive integer to check: ";
            cin >> num;
        } while(num < 1);
        if(isPrime(num)) {
            cout << "Prime!!!" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Not a prime." << endl;
        }
    } while(doAgain());
    cout << "Bye!" << endl;
}

bool doAgain() {
    while(true) {
        cout << "Again? (Y/N) ";
        char again;
        cin >> again;
        if(again == 'Y') {
            return true;
        } else if(again == 'N') {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

bool isPrime(int num) {
    if(num < 2) {
        return false;
    } else if(num == 2) {
        return true;
    } else if(num % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 3, max = sqrt(num); i < max; i += 2) {
        if(num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: one minor comment, `<math.h>` is a C library so you should be using `<cmath>` since I see you have a tag of C++.

Comment: What does `isPrime(9)` return?

Comment: @nhgrif `false`

Comment: Your `doAgain()` function should accept lowercase letters.

Comment: @happytime: He asked what isPrime (9) returns. He didn't ask what you think it returns. The reason why he asked should have been obvious - because he spotted an obvious bug in your code and wanted you to think about it. So if you reply "false" then I guess that you didn't check it and just made up your answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, your `isPrime` function returns incorrect results for the squares of odd numbers.

This is a pretty common oversight though, so don't feel too bad.

A better implementation of `isPrime` looks more like this:

```
bool isPrime(int num) {
    if (num <= 3) {
        return num > 1;
    } else if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 5; i * i <= num; i += 6) {
            if (num % i == 0 || num % (i + 2) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the first `if`, we handle the special cases of `0` through `3` as well as all of the negative numbers.

In the second, we eliminate all of the multiples of `2` *and* `3`.

Finally, in the catch-all `else`, we're handling everything else.

By starting at `5` and incrementing by `6`, we're able to skip all of our multiples of `2` and `3` which we already eliminated.  So we're checking 2/3rds of the numbers your original implementation checks.

Moreover, because we're dealing with integers, `i * i <= num` is a bit better than `i < sqrt(num)` (which actually needs to be `<=`).

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I meant `<=` in my code.

Comment: `isPrime(49)` returns `true`. You can change the increment to `i += 2` and it works.

Comment: @happytime It doesn't.  Double check the `if` within the `for` loop and make sure you copied it correctly.  On the first iteration of the loop, we try `49 % 5 == 0` (which is false), *but also* `49 % (5 + 2) == 0` (which is true).  I think you didn't copy the `for` loop body correctly.

Comment: `i * i` needs to be computed many times, whereas `sqrt(num)` only once... so as the numbers get larger, `i * i` is going to be slower. (Not sure when the switch-over is)

Comment: @derobert That's true.  I'm more concerned about the implicit conversion to and from floating point numbers in what should be a strictly-integer problem.  If `i * i` versus `sqrt(num)` is an optimization concern, then I'd recommend writing a `sqrt` function for integers... which not only would be better than going to and from floating points, but could also be significantly faster potentially.

Answer (score 8):

- Do not [use namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- You must've got a warning that `doAgain` may return without a value. What happens if I answer `Z` to the prompt?
- To test a single number, the approach is good enough. For multiple queries (as a `doAgain` loop suggests) I recommend to precompute a table of primes with your favourite sieve.
- `<math>`, `sqrt` and `max` are not strictly necessary. `i*i <= n` as a loop condition is good enough.
- Using `int` limits your program unnecessarily. `unsigned long` lets you check larger numbers.

Comment: `doAgain` can't return without a value.  If you enter `Z` to the prompt, it will ask you again... and again and again until you enter `Y` or `N`.

Comment: This answer would be better if your link were more fleshed out within the answer.  Links can die.

Answer (score 3):

Consider looking into sieves. Things like the [sieve of erastothenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or the [sieve of atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) are *really really* quick where it comes to finding primes.

Basically, you have an array of booleans called something like `isPrime`, and you mark off all of the numbers that are factors of something. Then you just go to the array index representing the value you want to check, and you get your answer pretty damn quick. So `isPrime[3] == true` and `isPrime[9] == false`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code there are `else` clauses that are unnecessary. The `if` statements above them `return`.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  We usually add more explanation with examples from the original code and with your proposed modifications.  You also may want to explain why it might be better to avoid unnecessary `else` clauses.